# how to serialize/deserialize a protobuf response from proto request

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protocols, protoc

`What I'm trying to achieve is saving the protobuf in the response as a **.proto** file so I could work with it later.

I can save it as **.proto** file, I couldn't figure out how to work with this later. I tried to write this result in a .proto format file like:

```
def requests_download(url) -> str:
    request.urlretrieve(url, 'test.proto')
```

But the file does not seem like a proper .proto file and I couldn't run it through the protoc compiler as follows: protoc -I=. --python_out=. ./test.proto

I get a bunch of errors like:

```
doc.proto:7398:6: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
doc.proto:7398:9: Interpreting non ascii codepoint 225.
doc.proto:7398:12: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
doc.proto:7398:15: Need space between number and identifier.
doc.proto:7398:16: Invalid control characters encountered in text.
```

To summarize, I'm just trying to serialize/deserialize the protobuf API response.

The protoc request link is 【methond : OPTIONS】: [here](https://pxqsellerbff.piaoxingqiu.cn/prod/seat/20230605/6465d5b543231c00015cc844/647d89e739bde00001519ff4_1_1685948904931.proto?versionNo=2&src=WEB&channelId=&terminalSrc=WEB)`

Comment: The attached file looks like actual protobuf message in binary format, not the protobuf schema i.e. `.proto` file. `protoc` won't recognize that. Don't you already have that schema?

Comment: is there any way i can convert it to a .proto file,Anyway thanks for your reply it's very helpful for me